# when back button click dialog box disappears and shows empty data view in android

Tags: android, android-intent, back-button

I have click one button, go to next activity but, that activity has not any data on list then display dialog box data not found, then yes for download data no for go to main menu. but here my problem is if that diabox appers whenever data was not found at that time when press back button then only disappers dialog,-- not switching main menu. I already define intent in back button like this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){


                Intent a = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(a);
                return true;

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

This works for only if data found. if data not found, then when press back it diaply empry ui of current activity not switching **mainActiviy**. why this? any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

When building your Dialog, you can call this 2 methods :

```
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

The user won't be able to dismiss the Dialog by clicking back or outside the Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy, I don't understand any part of your problem... But one sure thing is that you shouldn't use "onKeyDown" method just to check when back is pressed: you have a method, in the Activity claass, called "onBackPressed" to do this.  Then, other thing: how do you get your data? what kind of data is it (local, network...)? Can you post more of your code to explain how both of the activities work?